# Application.CalculateFull creates 1004 later in code

Tags: excel, vba

is anyone aware of negative impact of application.calculatefull?

the background is:

I have the following code that runs perfectly smooth:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xyz").Unprotect    
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xyz").Range("C18,K8,K10,K18:K19").Interior.Color = 65535
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xyz").Protect
```

If I put the calculatefull before in the code, the code stops here at the interior.color. if not, the code runs through.

any ideas where this conflict might come from?

Comment: Typo: you have a missing parenthesis after `Range` in your question.

Comment: Is there more code or is the error reproduceable with just these 3 lines?

Comment: thanks, typo corrected. there are hundreds and hundreds lines of code. this is just where the error happens, 1004. I also tried to counter it with .activate before the .unprotect, but that also does not help. what further parts of the code would you need? I have now also tried with calculation fullrebuild but same error.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Try to build a minimal example of code that is able to reproduce the error alone without the other lines of code (especially if there are hundreds of lines of code it impossible to tell which one is causing the error).

Comment: so I have resolved the issue by coloring each cell individually instead of defining the range as above with the ",". there seems to be a relation between such a range definition, the calc full and the run-time 1004. Not sure why, I guess this is a simple bug in Excel.